# Collection navigation properties may NOT be set

Tags: knockout.js, breeze, single-page-application

I have been building my first SPA app, spring-boarding off the great work from John Papa's jumpstart.

The issue that I'm having is that when I try to perform an Expand via breeze, or simply select all of the fields, I'm getting an issue from Breeze during the mapping of my child collections. newValue.entityAspect is undefined

if I query via my api via a select clause, all is well, if I call the table directly, 'Positions' directly, I get the navigation error on the chartVal object. 
[image]
[image]

```
var query = EntityQuery.from('Positions')
           //.select('id, endDate, gauge, hoursPerWeek, memberId, title, summary, startDate, totalHours, weightedHours, company, compensation')
             .where('memberId', '==', id)
             .expand('Company, ChartVals')
             .orderBy(orderBy.positions);

            return manager.executeQuery(query)
                .then(querySucceeded)
                .fail(queryFailed);

            function querySucceeded(data) {
                var list = partialMapper.mapDtosToEntities(manager, data.results, entityNames.position, 'id');
                if (observables) {
                    observables(list);
                }
```

The query above will succeed, then make a call to MapDtosToEntities (courtesy of John Papa)

function mapDtosToEntities(manager, dtos, entityName, keyName, extendWith) {
            return dtos.map(dtoToEntityMapper);

```
        function dtoToEntityMapper(dto) {
            var keyValue = dto[keyName];
            var entity = manager.getEntityByKey(entityName, keyValue);
            if (!entity) {
                // We don't have it, so create it as a partial
                extendWith = $.extend({ }, extendWith || defaultExtension);
                extendWith[keyName] = keyValue;
                entity = manager.createEntity(entityName, extendWith);
            }
            mapToEntity(entity, dto);
            entity.entityAspect.setUnchanged();
            return entity;
        }

        function mapToEntity(entity, dto) {
            // entity is an object with observables
            // dto is from json
            for (var prop in dto) {
                if (dto.hasOwnProperty(prop) && prop !="entityAspect") {
                    entity[prop](dto[prop]); <-- tanks here on children
                }
            }
            return entity;
        }
    }


/// <summary>
/// TODO: Update summary.
/// </summary>
public class Position : PersistableObject
{
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Weighted hours based on Half-Life.
    /// </summary>
    public int CreditMinutes { get; set; }

    public int? CompensationId { get; set; }

    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Code to hold measure of completeness. 10 = complete 0 = not complete.  
    /// </summary>
    public int Gauge { get; set; }

    public int? HoursPerWeek { get; set; }

    public bool IsCurrent { get; set; }

    [StringLength(40)]
    public string LinkedInId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int MemberId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(40)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [StringLength(400)]
    public string WeightedWords { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adjusted Experience score Based on half life
    /// </summary>
    public int Score { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(2000)]
    public string Summary { get; set; }

    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    public decimal? SalaryEnd { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Hourly salary - let users enter hourly, monthly, annual etc
    /// </summary>
    public decimal? SalaryStart { get; set; }

    public decimal TotalHours { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Total Man-hours Multiplied by Gauge reading
    /// </summary>
    public decimal WeightedHours { get; set; }

    public int VisibilityId { get; set; }

    public Company Company { get; set; }

    public Member Member { get; set; }

    public virtual Compensation Compensation { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; } 

    public virtual ICollection<ChartVal> ChartVals { get; set; } 

}


public class ChartVal : PersistableObject
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(40)]
    public string Key { get; set; }

    public double Value { get; set; }

    public string Percentage { get; set; }

    public int PositionId { get; set; }

    public virtual Position Position { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks for taking a moment to check out my issue. I appreciate your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this as well. I believe the solution will involve detecting if the property is a collection and iterating over it to add the items one by one. I have not attempted to do this as I am stil trying to decide if it is the *right* thing to do

I did not intend this as an answer per-se but as an indication that someone else has followed the same track as the poster and would be interested in any response from the community on this.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, a partial User entity that has an 'imageUser' navigation property.

I just changed John Papa's mapDtosToEntities "mapToEntity" function to this and it seems to be working - I'm new to all this so I can't guarantee the integrity of the navigation properties in relation to saving changes but it's definitely mapping the associations as I've created an 'imageUrl' computed property that retrieves the first association and displays it in an image element (i.e. seeing is believing):

```
        function mapToEntity(entity, dto) {
            // entity is an object with observables
            // dto is from json
            for (var prop in dto) {
                if (dto.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                    if (typeof(dto[prop]) != "object") {
                        entity[prop](dto[prop]);
                    } else {
                        entity[prop] = ko.observable(dto[prop]);
                    }
                }
            }

            return entity;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

IN the end, I wound up forgoing the John Papa mapDtosToEntities mapper method and just looping over my collection...

```
function querySucceeded(data) {
                var list = [];
                for(i = 0; i< data.results.length; i++)
                {
                    list.push(data.results[i]);
                }
                observables(list);
            }
```