# John Pappa Partials and BreezeJS using direct support in Entity Framework for this versus doing projections in breezejs

Tags: breeze

Having run into this issue:
[Collection navigation properties may NOT be set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16152545/collection-navigation-properties-may-not-be-set)
myself for exactly the same reason

and posting this suggestion on uservoice
https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions/suggestions/3796779-repository-sample-that-serves-view-models-

After seeing the great new compact meta-data feature and reviewing the edmunds sample I am trying to put it all together and come up a solution that allows me to  serve DTO's/View models versus full domain objects from a ef-codefirst web api back end and I have come up with two scenerios.

1)Use web api to return the DTO's/create the metadata in JS and use the where parameters to do filtering as required) thus as I understand it the entities can be tracked by breeze. The problem with this is that I will have to override save changes and convert dtos/viewmodels back to EF domain objects and save them. I am not certain that this is either as simple/ or as complex as I can see it being. Basically my proposed algorithm for this is to remove root objects and related children from the change set as DTOs and map them back to Domain objects which can then be added to the context and saved (seems like a lot of work and I am not totaly sure that the order this has to be done in is always *knowable*)

2) Follow Julie Lermans lead from the Pluralsight Enterprise EF couurse and create the partials directly in EF using code first and just let breeze work as designed. (in the course Julie creates stripped down models of Customer which have attributes placed on them that tells EF to map it to the customer table)

I would love to hear anyones thoughts on this. I am personally leaning towards #2 but I may yet be persuaded to choose #1 if there is a chance of a tool to generate the metadata from my C# clases or if the implementation of SaveChanges can be shown to be manageable and not turn into rewriting half of what EF is supposed to be doing for me)

Comment: if you can create stripped down versions and it suits your needs, sure, go for it. I avoid DTO's unless i truly need them. Usually I dont

Answer (score 0):

I was looking into the same issue myself and I ended up going with option 2. For my situation, I felt that I had more control going with option 2 and that I was better able to map my data the way I wanted without feeling that I had more layers than my personal project needed. Julie Lermans "Shrink EF Models with DDD Bounded Contexts" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj883952.aspx) was a very helpful article for me as well.